# Shared Redux Different App stores.. how?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm in a bit of head scratcher here. I have two apps. They are separate tools. BUT, one of the tool 1, uses part of tool 2. HOW can tool 1 get at and into tool 2 Redux state? Is there a middleware that enables me to bind them somehow.

TOOL APP1 --- has its own redux store
TOOL APP2 --- has its own redux store

I need a behavior from APP2 for APP1. So, instead of "building" a new version, just import APP2's sub section and use that.... NOW, here is the rub. APP1 now needs to know how to set, and retrieve the states it stores in APP2 sub component....

Is there a methodology in place for redux to do this, or ?

Worse comes to worse, I guess I can store the APP2 sub component state in localStorage or redis etc.. and then I can hydrate APP1 with it.. but....

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by needing a "behavior" from APP2 for APP1. You can certainly share components between different apps and your components should be providing the behavior of your apps. Redux is mainly for managing state *data*. If you could provide a minimal code example and get more specific it would be really helpful, as right now it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't have the code yet, I am building it out and want to make sure I do it the right way. For instance. In APP2, lets say it has its "own" state with its own actions. Are you saying that in APP1, I also have the same actions etc.. so I just instantiate the "same" store?

Comment: I think using local storage or redis will weigh on your app1 performances. It will add a delay of a few ms on every action which needs the other APP. If the synchronisation between apps 1 and 2 are not millisecond-time critical, I would suggest to store a copy of tool2 state in tool1 state and update it every X seconds through a specific tool1 action. That way, you won't delay the action execution and you will have a clear view at a given point in time, of which version of tool2 state has been used by tool1.

Comment: but how can I communicate between the two stores so that when I import/use/ a component from APP2, I can get access to its store? That is issue.... APP1 needs to be able to reach into APP2 store and get out info. I was hoping there was a middleware that would allow a merge of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

Not so difficult.

You can do it by providing shared Container components (means wrapped by calling `connect()` of react-redux), shared Reducers, shared Actions (with Action Creators), and shared Middlewares. Then, you use Container components, insert Reducers, and apply Middlewares in your main application.

This is a demo app contains shared self-contained components.
https://github.com/kuy/popover-profile

Timeline App: [Online Demo](http://kuy.github.io/popover-profile/timeline.html)
Message App: [Online Demo](http://kuy.github.io/popover-profile/message.html)

Please hover username in the pages. You will get popup profiles.

These two apps share a Popover Profile component, like Gmail's or SoundCloud's profile tooltip on mouseover names. No only sharing state, this component communicates with (fake) API server. This can be done by a shared Middleware using [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga).